# Use native dll in ASP.NET application in browser (on the client side)

Tags: asp.net, activex

We have an ASP.NET application for e-banking, and we need to implement a digital signature there - so that clients of the bank could send orders to the bank and sign them cryptographically with a digital signature (using their private key).

I have a native dll that contains specific cryptographic functions - and we need to use this dll - on the client side.

The question is: **how to call a native dll from the web browser**?

We can make an ActiveX and load it from the html page, and use JavaScript to communicate with the ActiveX. The **ActiveX** can the **call the native dll**. Is this scenario technically possible?

Are there other options to solve this problem?

Regards,
Mikhail